# how to import public key into RSA for encrypt in .net core

Tags: .net-core, rsa, public-key-encryption, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-1.1

I have publicKey.key, I want to import that to rsa encrypt

this is my code :

```
using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
{
    var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("012345678901234567890");

    byte[] publicKey = File.ReadAllBytes("text/publicKey.key");

    var result = rsa.Encrypt(key, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:** 2021-11-29 - Update answer that's two years out of date, to include .NET Core 3.0 API

.NET Core 3.0+ can load BER-encoded key file formats (not the textual/PEM format) via format-specific methods:

- AsymmetricAlgorithm.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo
- AsymmetricAlgorithm.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey
- AsymmetricAlgorithm.ImportEncryptedPkcs8PrivateKey
- RSA.ImportRSAPublicKey
- RSA.ImportRSAPrivateKey
- ECDsa.ImportECPrivateKey
- etc

.NET 5+ can also load the PEM format keys via a general dispatcher (since the PEM label identifies the format):

- AsymmetricAlgorithm.ImportFromPem
- AsymmetricAlgorithm.ImportFromEncryptedPem

Neither .NET Framework nor older versions of .NET Core (which were all that existed at the time of the original answer, and are now all out of support) have a built-in way to load bare key files.

For those environments, you have a couple of options:

- Wrap the public key up into a certificate and use `cert.GetRSAPublicKey()`
- Use `openssl rsa -in text/publicKey.key -text -noout` to copy all of the hex values for each of the fields, and import them directly into an `RSAParameters` structure (then call (`rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParams)`)
- Study [ITU-T X.680](https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-X.680-200811-S!!PDF-E&type=items) (ASN.1), [ITU-T X.690](https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-X.690-200811-S!!PDF-E&type=items) (DER), [PKCS#1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#appendix-A) (RSA), and [RFC 7486](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468) (if you want to read PEM-encoded keys) to read the key file, then parse it into an `RSAParameters` structure, and use `rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParams)`.

It's worth noting that this has been identified as a gap in .NET and is currently marked for .NET Core 2.1 (though it's always possible it doesn't make it): https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/20414.  (Edit: It didn't make it for 2.1, it made it for 3.0)

Answer (score 0):

Try [ImportRSAPublicKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importrsapublickey?view=netcore-3.1#System_Security_Cryptography_RSA_ImportRSAPublicKey_System_ReadOnlySpan_System_Byte__System_Int32__) / [ImportRSAPrivateKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importrsaprivatekey?view=netcore-3.1#System_Security_Cryptography_RSA_ImportRSAPrivateKey_System_ReadOnlySpan_System_Byte__System_Int32__)

Your code should look like this

```
    ...
    using( RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
    {        
      var publicKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(yourPublicKey);

      rsa.ImportRSAPublicKey(publicKeyBytes,bytesRead:out int _);

      var encryptedResult = rsa.Encrypt(yourData, RsaEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
    }
    ...
```